# Inserting large amount of data through wcf REST

Tags: asp.net, wcf-rest

I have an ASP.NET web application where i am using WCF 4 REST services to insert and get data from the database. But when trying to insert large amount of data like data for 1000 employees i am getting the error 'Unexpected End of File'.

Can anyone suggest a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u set buffer size in binding tag in config file? check this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/wcf/thread/00e27d83-75a0-405a-85bb-244f94086a53

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the Max sizes in the web.config on the WCF services and possibly in the App/Web config file on the client side.  It needs to look something like this:

```
<binding name="NewBinding0" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for REST service.

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```